# No preview display in Search result after configuring Office Web Apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

I have recently configure existing Office Webs to use SSL and https url. Our configuration is 1 SharePoint server and 1 SharePoint Web Apps.

In Office WebApps Server

```
 Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL "https://contoso.com/" -ExternalURL "https://contoso.com/" -SSLOffloaded -certificate "contoso.com2022" -AllowHTTP:$True
```

It configured without any issues.

In SharePoint server.

1. Removed all exisiting binding

   Remove-SPWOPIBinding -All
2. Binding again

   New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "CONTOSO.COM" -AllowHTTP
3. Set WOPI ZOne

   Set-SPWOPIZone -zone "internal-http"

In the SharePoint site. When I tried to search any document with pdf, excel or word. It did not display preview and not error display as well. When I attempt to open any document, it downloaded the document instead preview in browser. Before configure using SSL and https, it working fine.

Anything that I missed?

Comment: If you log on to SharePoint 2013 by using the System Account, you won't be able to test the connection between SharePoint 2013 and Office Web Apps Server. Log on with a different account to test the connection.

Comment: No , I am checking in the browser outside the server using normal account

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/configure-office-web-apps-for-sharepoint-2013#problem-when-you-select-the-new-document-link-in-a-sharepoint-library-youre-prompted-to-upload-a-document-instead-of-having-the-option-to-create-a-new-office-document-choosing-single-clicking-an-office-document-opens-the-file-in-the-client-application-previews-of-office-documents-are-not-displayed